# Storyboard and single UIViewController orientation lock

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, storyboard, monodevelop

I have made my application with storyboard and i have set in project option -> Supported Device Orientation -> All Orientation (Portrait, Landscape Left, Landscape Right, Upside Down), because i want that views rotates as wheel my device. Views are pushed by 
Interface Builder (with Segue method) in a NavigationController.

Now i have a single View Controller (TestViewController ), which is part of the storyboard, that i want to lock Orientation (just Portrait). I have made override of those methods, but TestViewController rotates as the others. ShouldAutorotate is not called, SupportedInterfaceOrientations fires but result is same as others views.

```
public partial class TestViewController : UIViewController {
...
    public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
     return false;
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;

    }
...
}
```

Environment

- MonoTouch 6.06
- Xcode 4.5.2
- MonoDevelop 3.05

Comment: Are you overriding these methods in your `AppDelegate` also? You might have to do that before they are called on each controller.

Comment: but if i do that in my AppDelegate that are valid for all ViewControllers?

Comment: Yes, and then you can override it in specific controllers that are different from your `AppDelegate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to set in AppDelegate Supported Interface Orientation as like this

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations (UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
        {
            if (forWindow != null && forWindow.RootViewController != null) {
                UINavigationController nav = forWindow.RootViewController as UINavigationController;
                if(nav.VisibleViewController is TestViewController){
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
                }
            }
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
        }
```

Comment: You should also be able to just return All in this method and override `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` on your `TestViewController`.